# How can I access tags from inside a CloudFormation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have an AWS PowerShell script that passes tags via the `-Tag` parameter on the `Update-CFNStack` and `New-CFNStack` cmdlets.

From inside a CloudFormation template I need to copy some of these tags to environment variables on an ECS Task Definition.

How can I access the value of these tags using something like `!GetAtt`?

Comment: I think you can't reference stack-level tags from the templates. They only propagate to the resources. In my view, you would have to write custom resource, which would get the tags and update the environment variables of the task definition.

Comment: You want to get the tags and pass them to another command?

Comment: I have a script that passes the same values as both parameters and tags. The parameters get assigned to environment variables on the task definition. I was hoping to eliminate the duplication by dropping the parameters and referencing the tags from within the YAML template file. @Marcin’s suggestion seems like a good idea,but I haven’t been able to figure out how to do it.